# Heroku db:push error Sequel::AdaptorNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- pg

Tags: ruby, database, heroku

I get this error when running Heroku db:push --app myapp.

"Sequel::AdaptorNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- pg"

Oddly heroku run rake db:schema:load and seed and migrate- all work correctly

I have the pg gem installed and have updated the heroku, taps and sequel gems.

The command auto detects my local postgres db correctly.

I have run heroku apps to make sure my app name is correct.

I have also run heroku info and see that a shared database exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to rails and heroku. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Heroku

I know I'm not addressing your exact issue, but since you're using pg locally, I suggest you use pgbackups instead of taps:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

It's a lot faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

You rails app doesn't have postgres gem or the pg gem in your Gemfile. Heroku uses Postgres as the database, so it needs the pg gem to make things work.

You will need to add that to your Gemfile, may be in the "production" group if you are only using postgres on heroku.

```
group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
end
```

and locally just do "bundle install --without=production'

Comment: I do have the pg gem in the gem file